# Wrong lib dir selected on luarocks/gcc build of cqueues rock

Tags: raspbian, debian-buster, luarocks

I am trying to install http via luarocks on raaspberry pi 4 running latest raspbian / pi os.

Not sure if it's specific to just `cqueues` rock, but lua while trying to build, luarock (or gcc?) tries to find `libcrypto.so.*` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`, while it's actually in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcrypto.so` on Pi OS.

```
Error: Failed installing dependency: https://luarocks.org/cqueues-20200726.51-0.src.rock - Could not find library file for CRYPTO
  No file libcrypto.a in /usr/lib
  No file libcrypto.a in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file libcrypto.so in /usr/lib
  No file libcrypto.so in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
  No file matching libcrypto.so.* in /usr/lib
  No file matching libcrypto.so.* in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
You may have to install CRYPTO in your system and/or pass CRYPTO_DIR or CRYPTO_LIBDIR to the luarocks command.
Example: luarocks install cqueues CRYPTO_DIR=/usr/local
```

How to fix this more generically than setting of `CRYPTO_DIR`, as suggested in the message.

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary workaround, but I need a more generic fix, as it'll be a pain to set syms for every .so dependency.

```
luarocks --local  install cqueues CRYPTO_DIR=/usr CRYPTO_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf OPENSSL_DIR=/usr OPENSSL_LIBDIR=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
```